# Script or Application that will do md5 checking

Tags: md5, checksum

Is there a program, or a script out there that can compare the md5 checksum of files I tried to create my own, but i'm having problems with any files that have a space in them, so I was wondering if it'd be easier to just use an application.  md5deep is something I downloaded that returns the checksum.

```
rm md5mastervalue
for i in `ls /media/disk`; do md5deep -rb /media/disk/$i >> md5mastervalue; done
for d in 1 3 ; do cp -rf /media/disk/ /media/disk-$d &  done
wait
rm md5valuet1
rm md5valuet3 
for k in `ls /media/disk`
do
    for f in 1 3; do md5deep -rb /media/disk-$f/$k >> md5valuet$f; done
done
for n in 1 3; do diff md5mastervalue md5valuet$n; done
echo Finished
```

Answer (score 1):

are you on linux? if so, you can use `md5sum`, or `sha512sum` (better security). Example, create a base line of your files

```
$ sha512sum * > baseline.txt
```

then, the next time you want to check, just use `-c` option, eg

```
$ sha512sum -c baseline.txt
```

Comment: Well, the reason I didn't use the md5sum is because it didn't work recursively, which md5deep does, all that code will work fine for any files that do not have any spaces in them

Comment: it is not difficult to use it recursively, just combine it with `find`, or do a normal shell version using globstar with for loop (bash 4.0).